# Android - Get URI from Picture that i just have taken (without save the image again)

Tags: android

I've found a lot of answers for questions like mine but they doesn't make sense for me. Let me explain.

I have a ImageButton that let the user take a picture and display it on interface. When i try to get image URI, it returns null:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
```

I've made some searches on internet and found solutions like:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    try {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            updateProfilePicure = Boolean.TRUE;
            switch(requestCode){
                case 0:
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    Object xx = data.getData();
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                    Uri tempUri = getImageUri(imageBitmap);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                    break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Uri getImageUri(Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
            ApplicationContext.getInstance().getContext().getContentResolver(), inImage,
   "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

For me, it doesn't make sense because when the call goes to method **onActivityResult()**, the picture is already saved on DCIM folder and don't have any reason to save it again. So why should i use it?

Is possible to find another way to retrieve the URI from captured image?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: That depends. If you don't add a File when starting the camera intent then you will not get the File Uri and 'data' will return a bitmap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the picture is already saved on DCIM folder and don't have any reason to save it again.

Not necessarily. Quoting [the documentation for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE):

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field.

(the "extra field" here is an extra keyed as `data`)

The code snippet that you pasted is retrieving the `data` extra, and so the image is not stored anywhere.

> Is possible to find another way to retrieve the URI from captured image?

You already have the code for this, in your first code snippet -- if you are specifying the `Uri` as `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request, you will get a `Uri` back to the image that was taken in the `Intent` handed to `onActivityResult()`.